# jQuery nested click hander

Tags: jquery, performance, events, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following markup representing a `bootstrap` tab-element:

```
<div id="someDivID">

    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="theTabContent">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I bind the click-event as follows in `javascript`/`jQuery`

```
var $theDiv = $("#someDivId");
$theDiv.on("click", "ul li a", handleClickEvent);
```

Because of the content of the tab is rendered/added dynamically later I'll have e.g. a `bootstrap` dropdown inside the #theTabContent div: (taken from the docs)

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Dropdown</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Another action</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Something else here</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Separated link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Because of the nested ul>li>a the `handleClickEvent` function is called when changing the value of the dropdown (which is obviously not intended).
How can I get around this behaviour?

And what (if any) would be the difference between

```
$theDiv.on("click", "ul li a", handleClickEvent);
```

and

```
$theDiv.find("ul li a").on("click", handleClickEvent);
```

?

Obviously the second one (find) will only catch the intented click of the tab-anchor.
Sorry to ask. But, I don't get the point here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit click events to only those related to tabs:

```
var $theDiv = $("#someDivId");
$theDiv.on("click", ".nav-tabs", handleClickEvent);
```

In this case it will not react to clicks in dropdown.

Comment: Ok. But why is `$theDiv.find("ul li a").on("click", handleClickEvent);` working as well?
And what about performance? Is there any important difference?

Comment: `$theDiv.find("ul li a").on("click", handleClickEvent)` works because `<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">` is in DOM when you bind click events, but dropdwon is not yet. `$theDiv.on("click", ".nav-tabs", handleClickEvent);` is more effective because it's only one event handler vs  3 in case of handlers on each `ul li a`.

Comment: Got it. This makes totally sense now. Thanks. Will get on with your solution